# Manipulating and saving output from a for-loop in R

Tags: r, merge, plyr

I have two matrices, "dm" and "schedule":

```
dm<-matrix(c(5,3,6,9,3,8),2,3)
dm

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    6    3
[2,]    3    9    8

schedule<-matrix(c(6.3,5.3,15.2,9.7, 8.1,21.0),2,3)
schedule

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  6.3 15.2  8.1
[2,]  5.3  9.7 21.0
```

Now I would like to do a for-loop using the two matrices:

```
library(plyr)
for (i in 1:3){
  for (q in 1:2){
a<-data.frame(t(sort(runif(dm[q,i], 0, schedule[q,i]))))
l<-list(a)
p<-do.call(rbind.fill, l)
print(p)
  }
}
```

And the results obtained are:

```
      X1       X2       X3      X4       X5
1 1.1483 2.746123 3.846865 5.20824 6.028914
      X1        X2       X3
1 0.09545895 0.6899679 3.311584
     X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6
1 0.0373203 1.213415 3.450417 7.803174 11.28925 15.17946
     X1       X2       X3      X4      X5       X6       X7       X8       X9
1 0.9628973 1.922808 3.734731 4.45964 4.60855 5.756587 6.259947 6.707502 8.352062
    X1       X2       X3
1 3.087143 5.518346 6.078802
    X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7       X8
1 3.588025 6.493965 6.868749 7.912049 9.164231 9.993325 15.34702 19.83849
```

I want the results to look like this, and then store the results for further analysis.

```
     X1       X2       X3      X4      X5       X6       X7       X8       X9
1.1483 2.746123 3.846865 5.20824 6.028914     NA       NA       NA       NA
0.09545895 0.6899679 3.311584 NA      NA      NA       NA       NA       NA
0.0373203 1.213415 3.450417 7.803174 11.28925 15.17946 NA       NA       NA
0.9628973 1.922808 3.734731 4.45964 4.60855 5.756587 6.259947 6.707502 8.352062
3.087143 5.518346 6.078802    NA      NA      NA       NA       NA       NA
3.588025 6.493965 6.868749 7.912049 9.164231 9.993325 15.34702 19.83849  NA
```

I have been trying very hard, but I can not solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

#

```
                              **UPDATES**
```

#

After I applied the code:

```
set.seed(567)
library(plyr)
for (i in 1:3){
  for (q in 1:2){
w<-do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(1:3,function(i)
do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(1:2, function(q) 
data.frame(t(sort(runif(dm[q,i],0, schedule[q,i]))))))))
print(w)
  }
 }
```

I got 6 sets of results:

```
     X1        X2         X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8       X9
1 1.6432907 3.0827761  3.9863873  4.689270  5.515190        NA        NA        NA       NA
2 0.3970765 1.2801990  2.7206058        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
3 4.1608265 5.1831060  5.3924656  8.139031  8.928247  8.978007        NA        NA       NA
4 0.1635540 0.2541877  0.6130778  1.236997  2.179649  2.831193  5.068474  5.081584 7.246205
5 0.1284468 3.1131624  6.7266701        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
6 0.5639268 8.2686410 11.2430075 14.828371 17.526983 19.172721 19.464813 20.096544       NA
      X1       X2        X3        X4        X5        X6       X7        X8       X9
1 1.82632052 4.262909  4.508882  5.806028  5.864306        NA       NA        NA       NA
2 0.08290761 1.725326  4.665457        NA        NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
3 1.83091637 3.697634  4.624553  4.877007  6.616031 11.094916       NA        NA       NA
4 1.39282538 3.490440  3.498343  4.051373  6.513588  7.452566  7.95394  8.239656 8.248208
5 1.60726975 2.072848  5.048690        NA        NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
6 3.15490789 3.950510 10.608165 10.865790 11.574824 14.850330 14.97088 19.527449       NA
     X1        X2       X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8       X9
1 0.5606442 0.9977634 3.161933  4.026845  5.793865        NA        NA        NA       NA
2 3.5053743 4.3333727 4.379345        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
3 1.9297694 3.3119283 8.884994 10.295379 12.759272 14.756985        NA        NA       NA
4 1.6398505 2.0005113 3.588146  3.652551  3.952168  4.930368  5.321089  6.712174 6.996944
5 0.9400254 3.9303393 6.564849        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
6 3.1807685 3.8952143 5.277726  6.373959  8.384240 11.821046 13.534297 18.934086       NA
      X1        X2       X3       X4        X5        X6        X7        X8       X9
1 0.25905911 2.2612541 2.364979 3.344301  5.744027        NA        NA        NA       NA
2 0.38830469 3.9903400 4.882548       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
3 0.04137479 0.4478564 2.587154 5.421488  6.429712 14.736563        NA        NA       NA
4 1.29092839 2.2867913 3.645377 4.235872  4.448638  6.117092  7.037541  7.490561 7.670878
5 0.33135574 5.7413350 7.805096       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
6 6.23169085 7.5107094 8.141378 9.606699 11.043875 13.606426 17.330823 20.372078       NA
       X1        X2       X3       X4       X5        X6        X7        X8       X9
1 0.007934088 0.5045294 1.186808 2.990181 5.783975        NA        NA        NA       NA
2 2.493238768 2.8420446 4.999854       NA       NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
3 0.544283423 1.8838762 3.310545 4.060896 9.613281 12.354680        NA        NA       NA
4 1.837721876 1.8548055 3.816228 4.132309 5.269259  5.729938  7.471994  8.329342 8.550461
5 0.489360828 7.2928492 7.321177       NA       NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
6 1.323669112 2.7321133 2.819985 4.743785 6.727880 13.338897 17.495578 19.840468       NA
      X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8       X9
1 0.68498784 2.6040049  3.614236  4.069595  4.600384        NA        NA        NA       NA
2 2.57882444 3.5311153  5.116656        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
3 1.39984330 3.2426665  3.256548 10.461186 13.605143 14.513957        NA        NA       NA
4 0.08044902 0.1764063  1.771046  2.412206  3.734814  6.371065  7.352427  7.588615 9.392168
5 0.48088901 3.6171198  6.550506        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
6 0.68160481 2.6673476 10.728082 11.572912 11.665851 12.580821 14.796373 19.908947       NA
```

When I used the "write.table" command to export the results, with "print(w)" replaced by
"write.table(w, "file.csv", sep= ",", row.names=F)", only the *last* set of results showed up
in the "file.csv": (the 6th set of results)

```
      X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8       X9
0.68498784 2.6040049  3.614236  4.069595  4.600384        NA        NA        NA       NA
2.57882444 3.5311153  5.116656        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
1.39984330 3.2426665  3.256548 10.461186 13.605143 14.513957        NA        NA       NA
0.08044902 0.1764063  1.771046  2.412206  3.734814  6.371065  7.352427  7.588615 9.392168
0.48088901 3.6171198  6.550506        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
0.68160481 2.6673476 10.728082 11.572912 11.665851 12.580821 14.796373 19.908947       NA
```

Actually only the *first* set of results is what I would like to have, save to a ".csv" file, and use for further analysis (my original code produced this 1st set of results):
(the 1st set of results)

```
     X1        X2         X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8       X9
1.6432907 3.0827761  3.9863873  4.689270  5.515190        NA        NA        NA       NA
0.3970765 1.2801990  2.7206058        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
4.1608265 5.1831060  5.3924656  8.139031  8.928247  8.978007        NA        NA       NA
0.1635540 0.2541877  0.6130778  1.236997  2.179649  2.831193  5.068474  5.081584 7.246205
0.1284468 3.1131624  6.7266701        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
0.5639268 8.2686410 11.2430075 14.828371 17.526983 19.172721 19.464813 20.096544       NA
```

Comment: Check if this works `do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(1:3, function(i) do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(1:2, function(q) data.frame(t(sort(runif(dm[q,i],0, schedule[q,i]))))))))`

Comment: Dear akrun: I really appreciate your help. Your code has made my life easier. Some updates have been posted after I applied your code. Basically, it is very close, although there are still some teeny-tiny problems. If you can give me further advice, that would be fantastic. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess you don't need the `for` loop.  The `lapply` loops replace the `for` loops.  I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Dear akrun: The code works. It seems that my understanding of the family of "apply" functions is not good. I really appreciate your help. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 res1 <- do.call(rbind.fill, 
               lapply(1:3, function(i) 
                        do.call(rbind.fill,
                            lapply(1:2, function(q)
                              data.frame(t(sort(runif(dm[q, i], 0, schedule[q, i]))))))))

  head(res1,3)
 #         X1       X2       X3        X4        X5       X6 X7 X8 X9
 #1 0.3498861 2.969862 3.473222  3.851105  4.446656       NA NA NA NA
 #2 0.2395686 2.477478 3.297952        NA        NA       NA NA NA NA
 #3 0.1117403 0.422571 1.267864 10.168734 12.511853 14.32337 NA NA NA
```